# C# stopwatch Class

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, stopwatch

I'm pretty new to programming so would just like to ask the following question regarding the .net built in stopwatch class using system.diagnostics in C#.

Does it automatically take care of garbage collection each time it is called or would I still have to implement garbage collection?

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by 'implement garbage collection'? Stopwatch is a class like any other, and doesn't need any special handling.

Comment: And its not part of visual studio..visual studio is just an IDE.. its part of .NET framework.

Comment: In class when we create our own Timing class we force garbage collection but i find it a lot easier and more effective to just use the built in stopwatch. just want to know if it also does this automatically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never have to implement garbage collection.

You may have to manage resources. For that, check whether a Type implements `IDisposable`.
And when it does, use the instance in a `using() {}`block or implement `IDisposable` on your own class.

But the `Stopwatch` class is not `IDisposable` so in this case, no action is required.

Comment: Ok Thank you. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean with garbage collection the process of tidying up the memory after using variables, methods etc., all .Net languages (and so even C#) take this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You never have to implement garbage collection. That's the point if it.

If the class implements IDisposable then you can manage it resource wise with something like

```
using(MyDisposable myDisposable = new MyDisposable())
{
   myDisposable.DoSomething();
}
```